# Why does this use of IEnumerable, List, and Arrays seem to get modified when it shouldn't be?

Tags: c#

I have started learning c# and am confused by the following feature.

The following code uses a function Algs.Combinations(n,m) to produce an IEnumerable which contains the combinations of n objects taken from m. Its implementation is exactly as can be found on the Rosetta code page for combinations. For example, applying .toList() to Algs.Combinations(2,3) would produce the list [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]].

Now in the foreach loop I add each int[] to a new list. I also print out the values of each array(ie the combination) after turning it to a list and then using the built in ForEach. Everything works as expected.

In the next block I use the built in ForEach on my new list and it seems every int[] has become [2,2]. What is going on here? Presumably in my foreach I am not actually adding the integer array but some kind of pointer?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Examples
{
    class main
    {
        public static IEnumerable<int[]> Combinations(int m, int n)
        {
            int[] result = new int[m];
            Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
            stack.Push(0);

            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = stack.Count - 1;
                int value = stack.Pop();

                while (value < n)
                {
                    result[index++] = value++;
                    stack.Push(value);
                    if (index == m)
                    {
                        yield return result;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var l = Combinations(2, 3);
            var newL = new List<int[]>();
            foreach (int[] combs in l)
            {
                newL.Add(combs);
                combs.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.Write(p + " ")); // prints 0 1, 0 2, 1 2 
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            newL.ForEach(p =>
            {
                p.ToList().ForEach(q => Console.Write(q + " ")); // prints 2 2, 2 2, 2 2
                Console.WriteLine();
            });
         } 

    }
 }
```

Googling hasn't helped so far. Any links to literature I should look at will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only returning a single array from your `Combinations` function, but returning it multiple times with the values changed inside the array between each iteration.

Methods which use `yield return` are coroutines - in each `foreach` iteration they execute up to the next `yield` statement they find and then they exit, picking up where they left off in the next iteration. In your first `foreach` loop you are taking the enumerated `int[]` value and putting it into your `newL` variable - but it's always the same `int[]` value because `Combinations` only ever creates one array. The print out in the first `foreach` works fine because the coroutine is paused waiting for the next iteration to start.

You have a couple of options. The best option is to make your `Combinations` have a sane implementation, in that it returns a new object for each `yield return` statement. That might look something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int[]> Combinations(int m, int n)
    {
        while (weStillHaveMoreResultsToBuild)
        {
            int[] result = new int[m];

            while (value < n)
            {
                // fill result and break out of loop when done
            }

            yield return result;
        }
    }
```

Another option would be to not use `yield return` at all, and instead build a list inside `Combinations` and return that. This approach could take a lot more memory if your `n` and `m` values are large.

A third option is to make a copy of the objects returned by `Combinations` and store those instead:

```
newL.Add(combs.ToArray()); // Calling ToArray() will make a copy
```

This is my least favorite option, because it requires any caller of `Combinations` to know that the same object will be returned multiple times but changed in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This has **nothing** to do with using an `IEnumerable` or the yield statement. If you rewrite your "combination" function like this

```
    public static List<int[]> Combinations(int m, int n)
    {
        int[] result = new int[m];
        List<int[]> resultList = new List<int[]>();
        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        stack.Push(0);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = stack.Count - 1;
            int value = stack.Pop();

            while (value < n)
            {
                result[index++] = value++;
                stack.Push(value);
                if (index == m)
                {
                    resultList.Add(result); // <-- note what you are adding here
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

you will face the same problem (well *almost* the same, because now already your first for-each loop will print out a couple of "2 2" values repeatedly).

This is because each entry in `resultList` gets a reference to the same array `result`. And as @Erik correctly wrote, the correct solution here is to make copies of the `result` array, though I would do this within the `combination` function, for example by modifying the `yield`line in your original code like this:

```
 yield return result.ToArray();
```

That way, it is not the callers responsibility to make copies, eliminating the drawback Erik was talking of.

Comment: Yes I see. So I guess the original implementation is only useful if one wants to do something with the int array immediately after it's returned in the foreach loop.

Comment: @George231086: maybe. "Rosetta code" does not provide robust, bug-free, production-ready code (which is understandable, that is simply not the goal of that site).